# how to solve this inverse fourier $ f(x) =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} 1/\sqrt{2\pi}\ e^{-2\pi^2/s^2} e^{ i \ s\ x}ds$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, inverse

I have two functions f(x) and f(s).
f(s) is the fourier transform of f(x) and  tends to $$e^{-2\pi^2/s^2}$$
I need to take inverse transform of this f(s) to get to f(x).
(i need to prove f(x) tends to gaussian after this inverse fourier transform. )
I used this inverse fourier formula

$$  f(x) =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} 1/\sqrt{2\pi}\  e^{-2\pi^2/s^2} e^{ i \ s\ x}ds$$

I used euler formula  for this integral $$ e^{i \ x} = cos(x)+isin(x) $$

so i get $$ e^{i \ s\ x} = cos(sx) + sin(sx)  $$

then i put $$cos(sx) + sin(sx)  $$ in place of $$e^{ i \ s\ x}$$ , so that i get two integrals.

$$  f(x) =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  e^{-2\pi^2/s^2} cos(sx)dx +i \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi^2/s^2} sin(sx)ds $$

I use then $$ uv - \int^{}_{}vdu$$

each time i solve these integrals i get 0 as result.  I cant see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: f(x) must tend to gaussian after inverse transform according to the proof so it cant be 0.

Comment: Expect non-elementary functions. Mathematica says something about Hypergeometric functions, essentially $\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left| \xi \right|  \, _0F_2\left(;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{\xi
   ^2}{4}\right)-\sqrt{2} \, _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{\xi
   ^2}{4}\right)+\sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (\xi )$ modulo some constants.

Comment: Are you sure it's $e^{-\frac{2\pi^2}{s^2}}$? Because this function is not $L^1$, so you can't use the usual definition of the inverse transform

Comment: @mickep good lord....what a mess

Comment: Actually i need to prove central limit theorem in probability theory by using fourier formulas. in the end of the proof i have this fourier transform. If  the inverse of f(s) is taken then it should be seen f(x) (probability density function) tends to gaussian.  in one proof f(s) is chosen as $$e^{-2\pi^2s^2}$$ which is actually in my proffesors book.  In another proof i could find f(s) is chosen as $$e^{-2\pi^2/s^2}$$

Comment: but i ve computed it by choosing f(s) as  $$e^{-2\pi^2s^2} $$ Then we know is that computing $$  f(x) =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi^2s^2} e^{ i \ s\ x}ds$$ is easier because  $$e^{-2\pi^2s^2}$$ is an gaussian integral and approaches  $$ 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$$. so in $$uv -\int^{}_{}vdu$$ i can get v so easily? But i computed it that way but again i get 0 as result.

Comment: The Fourier transform of a Gaussian is itself a Gaussian. $e^{-k/s^2}$ resembles a constant with some missing near zero, so its Fourier transform may resemble a delta function more than a Gaussian (yes, one is a limiting case of the other). Computing the Fourier transform of a Gaussian usually involves completing a square.